# many to many in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many, inner-join

I have two tables,

[image]

want to copy/update **Code** from Table 1 in Table 2 against Email address.
Each email address have its own code. **Email is the only column available for Join.**

With my Query its update first Code to all other emails in Table 2. See my query

UPDATE table1 fb 
INNER JOIN table2 nb  ON fb.`email` = nb.`email` 
SET  fb.`code` = nb.`code`

did so many other tests, but it doesn't work. Any Suggestion ?

Comment: Emails are duplicated in both tables as well. see examples above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed table 1 has a column "Code" but table 2 has a column "code" (uppercase/lowercase)

If it becomes a hassle, just run two queries.

First grab the code for the first table

```
"SELECT code FROM table1 WHERE email='emailaddress'"
```

then update the code on the second table

```
"UPDATE table2 SET code='retrievedcode' WHERE email='emailaddress'"
```